# UIPopOver Title and Sub-Title

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uipopovercontroller

How can I set a sub-title of my popOverView ?

Description :
Here is what I am getting : I am able to set the title.
[image]

Here is what I want :I want the title and a subtitle on my popOverView.
[image]

How can I do that ?

Regards !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `UIView` with two `UILabel`s, either with IB or programmatically and set it to the `titleView` of the `navigationItem`. In the `UIViewController` that you present in the popover:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = myTitleView;
}
```