# How to display NavigationController-background within a UIPopoverController on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uipopovercontroller

How can i display the background of the NavigationController (including title/buttons) in my UIPopovercontroller on the iPhone?

At the moment it looks like that:

[image]

**In my PopoverView-ViewController:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

self.navigationItem.title = @"self.navigationItem.title";
}
```

**When calling Popover:**

```
InfoView *iv = [[InfoView alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoView" bundle:nil];


    UINavigationController *uc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:iv];


    self.pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:uc];
    [self.pop setDelegate:self];
    [self.pop presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:true];
```

**It should look like this:**

[image]

Comment: @Rayfleck, you can also use it on the iPhone!! Did you read the question and look at the picture??? Don't be to premature.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371508/uipopover-title-and-sub-title -- Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @rakete - yes I saw the picture, and was confused by it.  The iOS 5.0 library UIPopoverController class reference says: `Popover controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices. Attempting to create one on other devices results in an exception.`

Answer (score 2):

At first UINavigationController doesn't have own background, it shows background of content view controller. If you can show popover with navigation controller successfully, then check your InfoView. Does it's view has some background?

Second, I tried to execute your code multiple times in different configurations on iPhone, but always have received error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController
>   initWithContentViewController:] called when **not running under
>   UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad**.

And that was not surprise for me. Even if you could make it work, then Apple may reject your application.
**2.1 Apps that crash will be rejected** - Just test your code on several devices and see result.

Comment: I dont need the background of the content. I want to show the background of the bar, which includes the title and the buttons on the top of the navigation controller. You get this error because you have to override a method of the UIPopoverController-Class. Unfortunetly I can't say you which, because at the moment I have no access to the code.

Answer (score 2):

your code

```
InfoView *iv = [[InfoView alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoView" bundle:nil];


UINavigationController *uc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:iv];


self.pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:uc];
[self.pop setDelegate:self];
[self.pop presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:true];
```

is perfect just hide the default navigation controller and add a navigationBar in the XIB of InfoView.xib and write the cancelButtonAction there to perform the dismissal of the view or the detail of the tableview selection. It Works fine, Please check the image i have done the same way, and believe me it works fine.[image]

Comment: Thanks. Now I see a navigation bar. But it have the standard blue background. I want to the navigation "integrated" in the gradient of the border of the popover.

Comment: You can alter the gradient of type you wish. Choose your navigation bar style as UIBarStyleDefault, UIBarStyleBlack, UIBarStyleBlackOpaque. Also you can alter the color of the bar as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your code before the line `[self.pop presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:se..`:

```
uc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

See the documentation for the [modalPresentationStyle property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/modalPresentationStyle).

Comment: Thank you for your anweser. But unfortunely the background is still invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to paste in more of the code for your InfoView controller, as I suspect that's where the problem is.

Comment: Then that's where the problem is ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up your background view as a class?

```
    [pop setPopoverBackgroundViewClass:bgView];
```